# South Park: Camcorders and bags on top of the building

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

There are some bags and camcorders hidden on top of some houses and other buildings... I can't fire an arrow on them and there are no instructions on how to get those.

Does anyone know how do I reach those bags and what should I do with the cameras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will gain the ability to reach them after a certain point in the story. Specifically:

> During the first night, you will be abducted by aliens. This results in The New Kid getting an alien probe stuck in his anus, which can be used to teleport short distances using the alien technology (which might be the things you are mistaking for camcorders).